# Ban and Unban commands to work in all servers

Tags: discord.py

I've been programming a discord bot letely, and for its ban command here is the code i use:

```
@client.command(aliases=['Ban'])
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, days: int = 1):
    if get(ctx.author.roles, id=548841535223889923):
        await member.ban(delete_message_days=days)
        await ctx.send("Banned {}".format(ctx.author))
    else:
        await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention + " you don't have permission to use this command.".format(ctx.author))
```

However, if i try to use this on other servers, it just tells me i dont have the required role..
So how do I get the role ID for a new server the bot joins automatically or is there some other way to make this work?

Comment: Each role has unique ID, even roles with the same name have different IDs yet alone roles from different servers. The way you're doing it now you can only allow `ban` command to work for 1 role and no more than that. That also means it will only work for that 1 server who has that 1 role.

Comment: I've resolved this, you can use: ```@commands.has_permissions(<kick/ban)_members=True)```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [check for permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_permissions#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions) instead of looking for a specific role ID

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@client.command(aliases=["Ban"])
@commands.has_permission(ban_members=True)
async def...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a has_permission, like this:

```py
@client.command(aliases=["Ban"])
@commands.has_permission(administrator=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, days: int = 1):
    await member.ban(delete_message_days=days)
    await ctx.send("Banned {}".format(ctx.author))
```

You can then add a missing permissions error handler:

```py
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
    await ctx.send("You do not have the permissions required for this command.")
    return

  raise error
```